# Since we need space for recursive calls, is the space complexity of the recursive factorial is n?

Tags: algorithms, recursion, space-analysis

As [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Space_complexity), quickSort needs O(log n) extra space when the following conditions are met:

- In-place partitioning is used. This unstable partition requires O(1)
  space.
- After partitioning, **the partition with the fewest elements is
  (recursively) sorted first, requiring at most O(log n) space**. Then
  the other partition is sorted using **tail recursion or iteration,
  which doesn't add to the call stack**. This idea, as discussed above,
  was described by R. Sedgewick, and keeps the stack depth bounded by
  O(log n).

Now please consider the following method computing the factorial of `n` recursively:

```
private static int fact(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return n;
    }
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

There is no tail recursion. Does it mean that we need O(n) extra space for the call stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need up to $n$ stack frames for the recursion.  Therefore, you'll need $\Theta(n)$ space for these stack frames.

Comment: Why Big Theta rather than O?

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev See [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use).